# Haml form_tag is breaking javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have some haml code that is being loaded through javascript to add cells and rows to a table. I have it to where when the form is submitted it does it all on the page without reloading the whole page. I have everything working except for the form tag. I ran into this issue on a different page and the solution was to rewrite it in erb instead of haml. The haml form_tag escapes out of the javascript.

Here's my code

```
    -@products.each do |product|
        -if product[:suggested_category_id].nil?
            -pid = nil
            -cid = nil
            -save = nil
            -form = nil
        -else
            -form = form_tag("update_product_category",:method => :put, remote: true)
            -pid = hidden_field_tag("product_id", value = product[:id])
            -cid = hidden_field_tag("category_id", value = product[:suggested_category_id])
            -save = submit_tag "Save"
        -if product[:suggested_category_name].nil?
            -name = nil
        -else
            -name =link_to product[:suggested_category_name], "change_category/#{product[:id]}", id: product[:id], remote: true
        :plain
            var table = document.getElementById("product_table");
            var row = table.insertRow();

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            row.appendChild('#{form}');

            cell3.className = '#{product[:id]}';
            cell4.className = '#{product[:id]}';
            cell5.className = '#{product[:id]}';

            cell1.innerHTML = "#{product[:barcode]}";
            cell2.innerHTML = "#{product[:name]}";
            cell3.innerHTML = '#{name}';
            cell4.innerHTML = '#{product[:suggested_category_permalink]}';
            cell5.innerHTML = '#{pid}#{cid}#{save}';

    -if @db_products.next_page
        :plain
            $('.pagination').replaceWith('#{will_paginate(@db_products)}');
    -else
        :plain
            $('.pagination').remove();
```

Here's a response:

```
var table = document.getElementById("product_table");
var row = table.insertRow();

var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
row.appendChild('<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="update_product_category" data-remote="true" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="blmkKSyMOJHGiYIJZ+/G6DBUNZw7LHMK5MasdPFsol8=" /></div>
');

cell3.className = '648878';
cell4.className = '648878';
cell5.className = '648878';

cell1.innerHTML = "710425394065";
cell2.innerHTML = "Mafia II (Xbox 360)";
cell3.innerHTML = '<a href="change_category/648878" data-remote="true" id="648878">consoles</a>';
cell4.innerHTML = 'video-games/xbox-360/consoles';
cell5.innerHTML = '<input id="product_id" name="product_id" type="hidden" value="648878" /><input id="category_id" name="category_id" type="hidden" value="17983" /><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />';
```

Notice how Haml is inserting a new line after the  in the form on the row.appendChild. Is there a way to toggle haml to not add it's own linebreaks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`escape_javascript`/`j`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) helper method.  Then to use `appendChild` you'll have to create an element first, such as a `div`.  You may want to start with something like:

```
...
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '#{j form}';
row.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found is that Haml doesn't play well with javascript. If you are going to have a js file it should be an Erb file. So rather that your_file.js.haml it should be your_file.js.erb.